# Results from 2 tables

Tags: mysql

I have table transactions:

```
id  user_id  amount  tranx_type  deposit_id
1      1        23        4          1
2      2        34        3          
3      1        17        4          3
4      3        11        2          
5      1        44        4          5
6      2        30        1
```

Then table deposits

```
id  user_id  currency
1      1        usd
2      2        usd
3      1        eur
4      3        eur
5      1        usd
6      3        eur
```

We need to get the sum of the amount of the deposits in "usd" made by user_id=1.

`deposit_id` in table transactions is `id` in table deposits.

`tranx_type`=4 means deposit.

I this example the result would be **67**.

So far I am trying this:

```
SELECT SUM( transactions.amount ) as total_amount 
FROM transactions INNER JOIN deposits 
ON transactions.deposit_id = deposits.id 
WHERE transactions.user_id = "1" AND transactions.tranx_type = 4 
AND deposits.currency = "usd"
```

But no luck, I feel I am close but I am not sure why the query is not working.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: if you can create a http://sqlfiddle.com, it will be really helpful.

Comment: `I am not sure why the query is not working` ...what isn't working?  The query looks correct.

Comment: It is returning null

Comment: @EugineJoseph here it is: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c3bc7d/2/1  it is returning wrong amount please check and help me please. There are records of two currency types but it is returning positive amount for one type and NULL for the other type. Please help

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen There are records of two currency types but it is returning positive amount for one type and NULL for the other type. I recreated here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c3bc7d/2/1  Please help thank you!

Comment: I got it. Wrong user in the query. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing is wrong with your query, maybe you can tell us what is the error code

[Transaction](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FhfN1.png)

[image: Transaction]

[Deposit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AOROq.png) 
[image: Deposit]

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9jfMw.png)
[image: Result]

Comment: This is the real case: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c3bc7d/2/1 The thing is that there are records for 2 types of currencies but it is returning a positive amount for one and NULL for the other one. Please help thanks

Comment: I got it. Wrong user in the query. Thank you!